# Yii Framework How to Access Relational ActiveRecord by ID and get next?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

So I'm getting a bit lost with CActiveRecord in Yii.

Let's say I have the following simple models:

- Post

  - id
  - content
- Comment

  - id
  - content
  - post_id

So Post HAS_MANY Comment, I think the relationship should be fairly obvious from that description.

What if I want to get **all** comments, and then within that get a **specific comment** for something? Like I want to display a list of comments for a post, but show the content of just one of them(by PK).

So I have:

```
$this->post = Post::model()->with('comments')->findByPk( $pid );
 // this next line is an extra DB Query, right?
$this->comment = Comment::model()->findByPk( $cid );
```

But I want something like:

```
$this->post = Post::model()->with('comments')->findByPk( $pid );
// this is not valid code because the comments is an array
$this->comment = $this->post->comments->findByPk( $cid ); // <---
```

Do I just have to wrap that in a loop myself to implement findByPk the second time?

My second question is, can I do something like the following?

```
$this->post = Post::model()->with('comments')->findByPk( $pid );
$this->comment = Comment::model()->findByPk( $cid );
// Get the PK of the next and previous comments from the $cid comment
// again, not valid code
$this->next = $this->post->NextComment($this->comment);
$this->prev = $this->post->PreviousComment($this->comment);
```

Or do I again need to wrap my own loop over the comments?

I'm really just trying to take advantage of what Yii has to offer before I write extra code. The documentation always assumes you always want all of the relational data, it doesn't specify how to pick parts of the relational data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the first question is

```
$post = Post::model()->with('comments')->find('t.id = :post_id AND comments.id = :comment_id', array(
    ':post_id' => $somePostId,
    ':comment_id' => $someCommentId,
));
```

or

```
$post =  Post::model()->findByPk($somePostId);
$comments = $post->comments(array(
    'condition' => 'comments.id = :comment_id',
    'params' => array(':comment_id' => $someCommentId),
));
```

The second question: what do you mean by "next" and "previous" comment?
Next to what? To id or to create_time?

You can do for it something like this (for previous by create_time):

```
$post =  Post::model()->findByPk($somePostId);
$comment = Comment::model()->findByPk(someCommentId);
$previousComment = $post->comments(array(
    'condition' => 'comments.create_time < :comment_create_time',
    'params' => array(':comment_create_time' => $comment->create_time),
    'limit' => 1,
));
```

You can get more info about this topic [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) and also from official class reference for [CActiveRecord.find()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)

**Update**

If you want get all comments from db and than get one by id you can do it this way:

$post->comments is just an array. So you can loop through it and get yours as you described in the topic.

But also you can add a new method to Post model class (not comments because it's an array) like "findCommentById":

```
public function findCommentById($id)
{
    foreach ($this->comments as $comment)
        if ($comment->id == $id)
            return $comment;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: "next" and "previous" are not relevant, your example is fine for that, I just didn't know how to find related comments. So I think the thing to take away from this is that I can write `$post->comments(array(...));` to query the related comments with additional conditions, correct? I was never really clear on that but I will try what you have posted here.

Comment: The only problem with this answer, is I want to get **all** comments but **also** pick a specific one out of the group. I just wanted to avoid hitting the database again and I didn't want to write my own find loop if the functionality exists.

Comment: I have updated my answer, there is no such functionality but you can add this with Behaviour also. Or you can try find it at Yii Extensions page.

Comment: Okay so it's not an existing function. Thanks for the answer. I'll look into using behaviors, but your solution is simple enough for now (just putting that in the model)